# Golang add function to struct defined elsewhere

Tags: struct, go

I want to create a function on the `sql.Row` struct that scans a row into my struct `ErrorModel`. This is what I am doing:

```
func (row *sql.Row) ScanErrorModel(mod *model.ErrorModel, err error) {
    err = row.Scan(&mod.MessageId, &mod.ServiceName, &mod.EventName,
      &mod.Hostname, &mod.Message, &mod.CriticalRate, &mod.Extra, &mod.Timestamp)
    return
}

func (dao *ErrorsDAO) Fetch(id string) (mod *model.ErrorModel, err error) {
    row := dao.DB.QueryRow("select * from errors where message_id=$1", id) 
    return row.ScanErrorModel()
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error here:

```
row.ScanErrorModel undefined (type *sql.Row has no field or method ScanErrorModel)
```

Is it impossible to add a function onto a struct that is defined somewhere else like this? Or am I just making a syntax error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot define methods of non-local types. As per [Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or interface type and **it must be declared in the same package as the method.**

(Emphasis added.)

What you can do is create your own type and [embed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) the imported type into it:

```
// Has all methods of *sql.Row.
type myRow struct {
    *sql.Row
}

func (row myRow) ScanErrorModel(mod *model.ErrorModel, err error) {
    err = row.Scan(&mod.MessageId, &mod.ServiceName, &mod.EventName,
      &mod.Hostname, &mod.Message, &mod.CriticalRate, &mod.Extra, &mod.Timestamp)
    return
}
```