# struct embedding : cannot refer to unexported name os.fileStat

Tags: go

I was trying to embed following hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30805285/9488865) from a while ago.

```
// Has all methods of *sql.Row.
type myRow struct {
    *sql.Row
}
```

However, when I try https://play.golang.org/p/Vnyx4lTwISn throws error `cannot refer to unexported name os.fileStat`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type myFileStat struct {
    info *os.fileStat
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Could you please point me the right direction?

Comment: `fileStat` is not an exported name, you cannot use it outside the os package. If you need to embed file info, use os.FileInfo.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: While you refer to an answer about embedding, your example is not embedding another struct.
What is it exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

In go identifiers that begin with a lowercase letter are not visible. Hence the "unexported name os.fileStat" error.
See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

It sounds like you are after something like os.Stat and os.LStat. They return a FileInfo type that is derived from fileStat internally in the os package.

See the implementation of the unix os.Stat here https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a38a917aee626a9b9d5ce2b93964f586bf759ea0/src/os/stat_unix.go

Answer (score 0):

In Go, when the first letter of an identifier is capitalized, the identifier is public to any piece of code that wanted to use it.

When the first letter is in lowercase, the identifier is private and can only be accessed within the package it is declared.

[Exported/Unexported Identifier blog post](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html)